# Minecraft servers list is blank

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

My servers disappeared one day after I logged off. This happened to me before and they came back after resetting everything, but now they are not. When I add one it disappears again. It has happened 3 or 4 times after the first time.

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of a known bug with the **servers.dat** file (at least from the research I have carried out on this topic).

Open the game directory (press Windows Key and R at the same time) -> type in "%appdata%.minecraft" without the quotations -> Rename **servers.dat.tmp** to **servers.dat**.

Comment: This sounds like a plausible solution. Unfortunately, I can't test it.

Comment: @MrParrot what do you mean by that?

Comment: I can't deliberately break my own servers.dat file.

Comment: That's likely a permissions issue. Try this: Right click servers.dat, press Properties, untick Read-only at the bottom, press OK and then try again